# Align last li in the column to the left

Tags: css, html, wordpress-theming, html-lists

I'm trying to make spacing between li's, but the problem that the last li in the column doesn't float to the maximum left of the column width, Here's a screenshot:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Uve.png]

and here's the code:

```
<li>
    <div class="fimg"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('recent-thumbnails'); ?></a></div>
    <a class="fimga" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.latest-news ul {
}
.latest-news ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 230px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    overflow: hidden; 
    margin-right: 32px;
}
.latest-news .fimg {
    width: 250px;
    display: block;
    height: 180px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
}
```

and here's the function I used to get the recent posts:

```
function ensan_LatestNews() {
    $rPosts = new WP_Query();
    $rPosts->query('showposts=8');
        while ($rPosts->have_posts()) : $rPosts->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <div class="fimg"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('recent-thumbnails'); ?></a></div>
                <a class="fimga" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
            </li>   
        <?php endwhile; 
    wp_reset_query();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 4 lis per line using php :

```
$style = ( $i % 4 == 0 ) ? 'class="last-li"' : null;
```

Then in your css file :

```
.last-li{margin-left:0 !important;}
```

Be aware that if you want the design to be responsive you have to give the li the margin left back.

Anyway the function will be:

```
function ensan_LatestNews () {

    $rPosts = new WP_Query();
    $rPosts->query('showposts=8');
    $i = 0;
          while ($rPosts->have_posts()) : $rPosts->the_post();

       $i++;
       $style = ( $i % 4 == 0 ) ? 'class="last-li"' : null;

      ?>
        <li <?=$style?>>
             <div class="fimg"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail ('recent-thumbnails'); ?></a></div>
 <a class="fimga" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
        </li> 
      <?php endwhile; 
            wp_reset_query();
}
```

Comment: Worked like magic, the problem was exactly in the function that gets the recent posts! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the nth is the best way.

> .latest-news ul li:nth-child(2n) {
>
> }

for more info see this link
[CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)